# Does employment change during divorce proceedings affect spousal support/asset division?

Tags: united-states, new-york-state, divorce

Spouses A and B are divorcing. Divorce started in December 2023. It's a contested divorce, with no settlement, so goes to the judge. There are no dependents to complicate the picture.

In the middle of divorce proceedings, **B loses their employment** in January 2024.

- Would this job loss affect the spousal support/asset division? (I am not sure if this is the same question but the way I reframe this is "Does support take into account income at point of filing, or at point of judge's decision making?")
- Do the circumstances of job loss matter? (e.g. being fired for cause vs. laid off vs. voluntary resigning from the job by B)?
- What if B finds another job meanwhile, but it is much lower paid?
- Would the answer be affected by whether A or B made more money initially? (meaning barring job loss A or B would pay spousal support).

Jurisdiction: USA, if states differ - New York City.

Answer (score 0):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

In all provinces and territories, except for non-married couples in Quebec, when spouses separate, spousal support is to be determined according to the Spousal Support Advisory Guidelines.

The Users Guide has a section discussing the situation where the recipient's income decreases after separation or after a spousal support order has already been made. See [section 15(f)](https://www.justice.gc.ca/eng/rp-pr/fl-lf/spousal-epoux/ug_a1-gu_a1/p15.html).

The court will consider the reasons for the decrease in income. To the extent that it is truly voluntary, the court may impute income so as to not increase the support obligation.

> Where the recipient’s post-separation job loss is involuntary, issues of the connection to the marriage can arise, requiring consideration of factors such as the basis of entitlement and the length of time that has passed since the separation.

Where the decrease in income can be traced to a circumstance of the marriage (e.g. the spouse was in a more precarious junior position as a result of trade-offs made during the spousehood), this will weight in favour of increasing support obligations.

And even where the layoff or decrease in income is not traceable to the marriage, the resulting needs may be increased due to circumstances of the marriage or its breakdown. This would also weight in favour of an increase of support obligations.

Comment: You list 2 options (voluntary or caused by marriage circumstance) but what if it was NOT voluntary (layoffs) but unrelated to marriage?